# How to best report about the interaction of two risk factors?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction

I am struggling with a decision on how to report an interaction analysis.

Let's say I have a dataset, in which I want to explore the contribution of two risk factors: Hypertension and Diabetes, on the risk of death. We all know both are associated with a significant risk of excess mortality, even after adjusting for other potential confounders.

Nonetheless, I am now interested in exploring if the co-occurrence of the two is associated with a higher risk of death, compared to the occurrence of one only. From a clinical point of view, we expect such occurrence.

Two options come to my mind:

1. I can model an interaction in my Cox Regression model, `Hypertension*Diabetes`, and see how the occurrence of (let's say) Diabetes modifies the association (i.e., HR) of Hypertension with the risk of death, or...
2. I can create a new variable, `Hypertension_Diabetes`, in which I recode all the combinations (i.e., "None", "Only Hypertension", "Only Diabetes", "Both"). Then I could compare all levels against "None", and see how the hazard increase across the combinations.

What would be the most suitable method to communicate the relationship between the two risk factors? I suppose that, in the end, the meaning would be quite similar; perhaps the second method may be more easy to understand, although the first can test for the actual interaction between the two risk factors?

Comment: Aren't the methods equivalent?  If not, then please tell us what you mean by "model an interaction."

Comment: when you test for the actual interaction in method 1, you are actually testing if a simpler additive model would do the job of explaining the data well enough. I agree with whuber that the methods are equivalent, and I agree with you that the results you get with the second method may be easier to interpret immediately. \\ I would do both analyses, and report the results that better fit the scientific context.

Comment: @Ute, that's ok - I was wondering whether the two methods were equivalent or not. Do you think would be correct to report the results according to approach #2, and also with the "p for interaction" taken from the approach #1?

Comment: Yes, I think it is OK if you explain what you are doing. The two ways to set up the model formula describe exactly the same stochastic model, and they would yield the same predictions and $p$-values for equivalent hypotheses. Maybe some have multiple testing arguments against doing so, but I would just ruthlessly do it ;-)